# How to confirm files bundled in war file of a legacy Grails 2.4.0 project?

Tags: grails, war

There are some js files in the legacy code, which I don't see loaded in browser when we run the application using the `run-app` command.

We deploy the war of the project on production. We generate it using `war` command. I need to make sure that these js files are not bundled in the war. How do I check the same? I don't see any source directory paths in the BuildConfig.groovy file. Also, don't see anything relevant in web-app/WEB-INF/ -

applicationContext.xml
sitemesh.xml.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Unzip the war and search through the files.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make sure that these js files are not bundled in the war.
>   How do I check the same?

Look in the .war file.  A .war file is really just a zip file.  You can use something like `unzip -l somefilename.war` to list the contents of a war/zip/jar file or use whatever zip file interrogation tool you like.